# Magento 2.1.7 Frontend Error 'There has been an error processing your request'

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We are having an issue on our Magento store, when trying to login, create accounts or view account information there is an error stating:

There has been an error processing your request

Object DOMDocument should be created.

Error log:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:13663:"#0 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()
#1 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(258): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->read()
#2 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(166): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('stripe-payments...')
#3 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('stripe-payments...')
#4 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('stripe-payments...', NULL, Array)
#5 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'stripe-payments...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#6 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#7 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#8 /home/store/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#9 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#10 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#12 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#13 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(217): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#14 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Index.php(40): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#15 /home/store/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index->execute()
#16 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#17 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#20 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#23 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#26 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer_accoun...')
#29 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php(60): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#32 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#35 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(110): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/store/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#38 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#41 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#42 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#45 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'searchautocompl...')
#48 /home/store/public_html/vendor/mirasvit/module-search-autocomplete/src/SearchAutocomplete/Model/App/FrontController/Plugin.php(130): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Mirasvit\SearchAutocomplete\Model\App\FrontController\Plugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#51 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#54 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#55 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 /home/store/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#57 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 /home/store/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#59 /home/store/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#60 {main}";s:3:"url";s:18:"/customer/account/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `var/generation` is not writable. Make sure to set [proper file system ownership and permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html): `var, app/etc and pub/static` should be writable by web server.

Comment: I double checked all the folders for the correct permissions that you mentioned and they are all writable by the webserver.

Our store was working perfectly until yesterday when this issue started affecting customers

Comment: After that did you change anything or any kind of extension installation or else?

Comment: The only recent change we made was updating our stripe API to allow SCA payments, this was on the 6th.

Comment: Can you please restore all changes and check I think that will help you to check where the error is?